# Magento 2 remove print.min.css from head

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, css

i want to remove print.min.css from head of html i tried below code in theme xml file but it is not wokring

```
<head>
         <remove src="css/print.min.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Is your code in this file?

`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

Comment: yes, i have added code there

Comment: So, it has to work. You can check some points like: Have you removed from the correct theme? Have you cleaned the cache after removing it? Is this the correct path to the file?

Also, as magento docs say if it was added by a module you have to specifies the module path also.

You can see more about it [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove)

Answer (score 1):

**Override this file**

```
Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

**And add this code**

```
<head>
   <remove src="css/print.css"/>
</head>
```